# How do I conditionally select a UIViewController from a single UITabBar item and keep the TabBar visible

Tags: uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uitabbar

First question on S/O, so apologies if I haven't followed any protocols. I have been trying to display conditionally 4 different types of scene using 4 UIViewControllers from the same UITabBar item. It has to be the same item on the TabBar, because the UIViewController used is dependent upon data rather than user selection.

I know that subclassing UITabBarController is not advised, so I have set up a UIViewController that handles the conditional selection of the required scene (see code below). This works well, but despite trying everything I can think of, fails to show the TabBar at the bottom of the newly selected view. I have also tried using a UINavigation controller, but this was less successful. In Storyboard, I have tried all the different permutations of setting the view sizes and presentation styles, change the Bottom Bar to Tab Bar in simulated metrics and tried using Segues. None have produced the requisite outcome.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    int m = 1;

    UIViewController *viewController;
    if (m == 1 || m == 3 || m == 5 || m == 7 || m == 8 || m == 10 || m == 12 ) {
        viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"M31TVC"];
    }else if (m == 4 || m == 6 || m == 9 || m == 11 ){
        viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"M30TVC"];
    }else if (m == 13 ){
        viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"M29TVC"];
    }else if (m == 2 ){
        viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"M28TVC"];
    }else {
        // error code here
    }
    viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];


}
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who knows how to do this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to replace to controller that will be shown to the user, you should only replace its view. That means you should implement a Container View Controller:

- Create your UITabBarController and make one of its items a UIViewController
- Make that into a custom controller and add the following properties to it.

  ```
  @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *currentView
  @property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *currentViewController
  ```
- Add a UIView to the controller in the storyboard and connect it to the *currentView outlet.

Now, everytime the user reaches this point in your app, you are going to do the following:

```
UIViewController *viewController;
if (month == 1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 10 || 12 ) {
    viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"M31TVC"];
}else if (month == 4 || 6 || 9 || 11 ){
    viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"M30TVC"];
}else if (month == 13 ){
    viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"M29TVC"];
}else if (month == 2 ){
    viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"M28TVC"];
}else {
    // error code here
}

[self addChildViewController:viewController];
[viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

if (self.currentViewController){
    [self.currentViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

    [self transitionFromViewController:self.currentViewController toViewController:viewController duration:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{
        [self.currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.currentView addSubview:viewController.view];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.currentViewController removeFromParentViewController];
        self.currentViewController = viewController;
    }];
} else {
    [self.currentView addSubview:viewController.view];
    self.currentViewController = viewController;
}
```

This is what I did on my app to create a custom tabbed controller, instead of using the default UITabBarController.

Comment: Thanks Breno. Works perfectly. Considering the amount of time I've wasted on this, I hope your post will prove useful to others. That said, it is surprising how much one learns during all that 'wasted time'!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Remember to click the checkmark at the beginning of my answer so other people will know that it worked for you.

Comment: Hi Breno. I have just noticed that using this solution, the view does not autoresize, when switching to landscape, despite all the settings in storyboard being correct. Do have any thoughts on how this might be resolved? Thanks again for the solution.

Comment: I didn't have to do that in my app (it's portrait only), so I can't give you a ready made solution. My best guess is that you should set the view's Struts and Springs so they will resize it properly when the app is rotated. Paul Hegarty in CS193P has a class about it (It's number 5 I think). This is the iTunes link to it: http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255